# Hide specific tabs from users using express-authentication

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express-authentication-basic module in Nodejs for users authentication.

```
login = basic(function (challenge, callback) {
    if ((challenge.username === 'user' && challenge.password === 'test')) {
        callback(null, true);
    } else {
        callback(null, false, {
            error: 'INVALID_PASSWORD'
        });
    }
});



app.use(login); //middleware
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/details', detailsRoutes);
```

I want to hide specific tabs depending on the username and password.

If its an admin user name and password to show all the tabs.

Comment: you need to create a middleware

Comment: i created middleware its login as u can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by adding `if-else` option in middleware, following example may help you

```
login = basic(function (challenge, callback) {
    if (challenge.username === 'user' && challenge.password === 'test') {
        callback(null, true, {
            admin: false
        });
    } else if (challenge.username === 'admin' && challenge.password === 'test') {
        callback(null, true, {
            admin: true
        });
    } else {
        callback(null, false, {
            error: 'INVALID_PASSWORD'
        });
    }
});



app.use(login); //middleware
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/details', detailsRoutes);
```

and in routes,

```
if (req.authenticated && req.authentication.admin) {
    // send all tabs as this user is admin
} else if (req.authenticated) {
    // send limited tabs as user is not admin
} else {
    res.status(401).send();
}
```